# MDC web components - Deactivating focus from textfield not working

Tags: mdc-components

I am trying to implement an autocomplete input by using mdc web components. I have a menu selected event listener, where I want to deactivate focus on a textfield. I have tried that by using **MDCTextFieldFoundation** **deactivateFocus** method:

```
const inputFoundation = new MDCTextFieldFoundation(
  document.querySelector(".mdc-text-field")
);
menu.listen("MDCMenu:selected", e => {
  console.log(inputFoundation);
  input.value = e.detail.item.dataset.value;
  inputFoundation.deactivateFocus();
});
```

But, that is not working. In the console, I can also see that input's property isFocused is false, when textfield is still focused. You can see the whole codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mayer-lln7d?file=/src/index.js:220-318). What am I doing wrong here and what is the correct way of deactivating focus from a textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/):

> Deactivates the focus state of the Text Field. Normally **called in response to** the input **blur** event.

So `deactivateFocus` updates the state of the component, but it doesn't change focus.

You need to call `blur` yourself. For example like this:

```
document.activeElement.blur()
```

Comment: but, if I do that on input element I get blur is not a function

Comment: That's because input "element" is `MDCTextField` and not a **DOM**-element. You should either use `input.root_` ... but it's `protected`, or `document.querySelector(".mdc-text-field").blur()`. But as there can be only one focused element `document.activeElement` - is more than enough. And as I see you've already changed *codesandbox* with `document.activeElement.blur()` and it works, if I don't miss something.